# What does parameters like timeout, connectionTimeout, soTimeout, and infiniteSoTimeout mean in JedisPool?

Tags: redis, jedis

While defining a jedisPool object, various functions can be chosen from with varying parameters. I want to know what these parameters

- timeout
- connectionTimeout
- soTimeout
- infiniteSoTimeout

mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jedis uses [`java.net.Socket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) under the hood. The concerned parameters are all directly related to that Socket. Also, the naming of parameters comes mostly from there.

- `connectionTimeout` - timeout value (in milliseconds) to be used while establishing a socket connection.
- `soTimeout`/`socketTimeout` - timeout value (in milliseconds) to be used while waiting for a response from Redis server (during a regular command execution)
- `timeout` - this is simply a shortcut to use same value for both connectionTimeout and soTimeout
- `infiniteSoTimeout`/`blockingSoTimeout` - timeout value (in milliseconds) to be used while waiting for a response from Redis server **during a blocking command execution.** For example, [BLPOP](https://redis.io/commands/blpop/) is a blocking command.